# Gauge invariance to solve Dirac equation in external EM field

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, gauge-invariance, gauge

Consider a Dirac equation in external EM field $A_\mu$

$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m)\psi=q\gamma^\mu A_\mu\psi$

Consider a solution without EM field $\psi_0$. Let us do the gauge transformation $\psi_0\rightarrow\psi=e^{-iq\theta}\psi_0$ where $\theta$ is a dynamical field.

It is easy to prove that

$\partial_\mu\theta=A_\mu$

However this equation only has solutions if $\partial_\nu A_\mu=\partial_\mu A_\nu$ or the same as $F_{\mu\nu}=0$ which is obviously not always true. What other transformation we need to do to get to the final result?

My idea was to apply 4D Helmholtz decomposition on $A_\mu$ in that case $\theta$ would be a scalar potential and some vector field $\vec{v}$ would be a vector potential. However I couldn't find a formula for 4D decomposition of vector.

Answer (score 2):

So I think you went wrong in the statement $A_\mu = \partial_\mu  \theta$. This is incorrect. A gauge transformation in this theory is of the form $\psi \rightarrow e^{-iq\theta} , A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \partial_\mu \theta$. i.e. both fields transform as the gauge potential is not gauge invariant. Doing so reveals that instead of $ F = 0$ we get $\delta A_\mu = \partial_\mu \theta$ such that $\delta F = 0$ which is telling us that the field strength is indeed invariant under gauge transformations as expected.

Comment: But that ist not what I wanted. I wanted to solve the Dirac equation in external EM field, not to prove, that EM tensor is invariant under gauge transformations.